# Computing SGD classifier with logloss & L2 regularization without using sklearn and I am not able to compute loss & getting error in loss calculation

Tags: python, logistic-regression

```
def logloss(y_true,y_pred):                                     # compute log-loss                      
    log_loss = (-y_true * math.log(y_pred, 10) - (1 - y_true) * math.log(1 - y_pred,10)).mean()
    return log_loss
```

```
def grader_logloss(true,pred):                 # comparing log-loss using assert
    loss = logloss(true,pred)
    assert(loss == 0.07644900402910389)
    return True
true = [1,1,0,1,0]
pred = [0.9,0.8,0.1,0.8,0.2]
grader_logloss(true,pred)
```

Error I am getting

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-110-edd7da954047> in <module>
          5 true = [1,1,0,1,0]
          6 pred = [0.9,0.8,0.1,0.8,0.2]
    ----> 7 grader_logloss(true,pred)

    <ipython-input-110-edd7da954047> in grader_logloss(true, pred)
          1 def grader_logloss(true,pred):
    ----> 2     loss = logloss(true,pred)
          3     assert(loss == 0.07644900402910389)
          4     return True
          5 true = [1,1,0,1,0]

    <ipython-input-109-b96b3bba92ed> in logloss(y_true, y_pred)
          2     '''In this function, we will compute log loss '''
          3     n = len(y_true)
    ----> 4     log_loss = (-y_true * math.log(y_pred, 10) - (1 - y_true) * math.log(1 - y_pred,10)).mean()
          5     return log_loss

    TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'list'
```

I am not able to get what is operand type. I have searched but not able to get a clear picture of it.

expected result is

```
True
```

computing gradient

```
def gradient_dw(x,y,w,b,alpha,N):
    '''In this function, we will compute the gardient w.r.to w '''
    dw = x*(y - sigmoid(np.dot(w.T,x) + b)) - ((alpha*x)/N)
    return dw
```

computing gradient and comparing it

```
def grader_dw(x,y,w,b,alpha,N):
    grad_dw=gradient_dw(x,y,w,b,alpha,N)
    assert(grad_dw==2.613689585)
    return True
grad_x=np.array([-2.07864835,  3.31604252, -0.79104357, -3.87045546, -1.14783286,
       -2.81434437, -0.86771071, -0.04073287,  0.84827878,  1.99451725,
        3.67152472,  0.01451875,  2.01062888,  0.07373904, -5.54586092])
grad_y=0
grad_w,grad_b = initialize_weights(grad_x)
alpha=0.0001
N=len(X_train)
grader_dw(grad_x,grad_y,grad_w,grad_b,alpha,N)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-152-b22fd39ec68a> in <module>
     10 alpha=0.0001
     11 N=len(X_train)
---> 12 grader_dw(grad_x,grad_y,grad_w,grad_b,alpha,N)

<ipython-input-152-b22fd39ec68a> in grader_dw(x, y, w, b, alpha, N)
      1 def grader_dw(x,y,w,b,alpha,N):
      2     grad_dw=gradient_dw(x,y,w,b,alpha,N)
----> 3     assert(grad_dw==2.613689585)
      4     return True
      5 grad_x=np.array([-2.07864835,  3.31604252, -0.79104357, -3.87045546, -1.14783286,

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I don't know where my gradient evaluation is incorrect and and why assert function is failing even though I have tried a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Try to work with numpy arrays instead of lists. The error  mention you can't negate  a list by using "-"

Comment: thanks for the help. I have edited the code for further help. I want to know if my gradiant evaluation is correct or not. and also the error I am encountring in assert function even thought I have tried a.any(), a.all()

Answer (score 0):

Use a `numpy.array` to store your `true` and `pred`, and tweak your code a little bit
to use operations defined in `numpy`. Since ordinary `list` in python doesn't support element-wise operations such as  `-` and `*` and `+`, it has no `mean` method.

```
import numpy as np
def logloss(y_true,y_pred):                                     # compute log-loss                      
    log_loss = (-y_true * np.log10(y_pred) - (1 - y_true) * np.log10(1 - y_pred)).mean()
    return log_loss
def grader_logloss(true,pred):                 # comparing log-loss using assert
    loss = logloss(true,pred)
    assert(loss == 0.07644900402910389)
    return True
true = np.array([1,1,0,1,0])
pred = np.array([0.9,0.8,0.1,0.8,0.2])
grader_logloss(true,pred)
```

**Update for the new question:**
I assume your `dw` is a scalar since you have `grad_dw==2.613689585`. Then, in your `gradient_dw` function, change this line:

```
dw = x*(y - sigmoid(np.dot(w.T,x) + b)) - ((alpha*x)/N)
```

to this line

```
dw = (x*(y - sigmoid(np.dot(w.T,x) + b)) - ((alpha*x))).sum() / N
```

Besides, you should use `assert grad_dw==2.613689585` instead of `assert (grad_dw==2.613689585)`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have again edited the question and could you help me out for the later part of the code regarding error I am getting. Azuuu

Comment: @maddy Edited the answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the response but using your code for 'dw' giving me error : AssertionError - @Azuuu

Comment: Since I don't know about the function `initialize_weights` detail, I can't check the actual value returned. I suggest you check the logic of  `logloss`. Good luck! @maddy

Comment: okay thanks, I rectify my error. Thanks for the help once again @Azuuu